# NotImplementedError: The lemmatize parameter is no longer supported

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have run the code for my own similar gpt2 model, but the below Error was got it. How to solve this implement error in python.

```
corpus = WikiCorpus(file_path, lemmatize=False, lower=False, tokenizer_func=tokenizer_func)
  File "C:\Rayi\python\text-generate\text-gene\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 619, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: The lemmatize parameter is no longer supported. If you need to lemmatize, use e.g. <https://github.com/clips/pattern>. Perform lemmatization as part of your tokenization function and pass it as the tokenizer_func parameter to this initializer.
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus
import os
import argparse

# lang = 'bn'

def store(corpus, lang):
    base_path = os.getcwd()
    store_path = os.path.join(base_path, '{}_corpus'.format(lang))
    if not os.path.exists(store_path):
        os.mkdir(store_path)
    file_idx=1
    for text in corpus.get_texts():
        current_file_path = os.path.join(store_path, 'article_{}.txt'.format(file_idx))
        with open(current_file_path, 'w' , encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
        #endwith
        file_idx += 1
    #endfor

def tokenizer_func(text: str, token_min_len: int, token_max_len: int, lower: bool) -> list:
    return [token for token in text.split() if token_min_len <= len(token) <= token_max_len]

def run(lang):
    origin='https://dumps.wikimedia.org/{}wiki/latest/{}wiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2'.format(lang,lang)
    fname='{}wiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2'.format(lang)
    file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=origin, fname=fname, untar=False, extract=False)
    corpus = WikiCorpus(file_path, lemmatize=True, lower=False, tokenizer_func=tokenizer_func)
    store(corpus, lang)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ARGS_PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ARGS_PARSER.add_argument(
        '--lang',
        default='en',
        type=str,
        help='language code to download from wikipedia corpus'
    )
    ARGS = ARGS_PARSER.parse_args()
    run(**vars(ARGS))
```

Comment: @BoarGules No Still i got the same issue, If solve this type error please give the suggestions

Comment: The example code you are following is obsolete and broken. If you followed the instructions in the error, and that doesn't work, then show us what you tried and what error you got. If you don't understand how to follow the instructions, then you need to find some example or tutorial material that is up to date and doesn't use obsolete features of the package.  The developers of `WikiCorpus` have removed support for `lemmatize=True`. You can't magic it back into existence.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/train-gpt-2-in-your-own-language-fc6ad4d60171
@BoarGules I try this link and try to gather the data but the error was got it

Comment: Try submitting a comment to the author of the blog pointing out that the code it presents doesn't work with current versions of libraries it recommends. The blog is 2 years old. In a fast-moving field that is a very long time. Few bloggers or authors of 3rd-party tutorials have the time or inclination to keep their material  up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any actual documentation for this function, just some example page.

What I did was just calling:

```
corpus = WikiCorpus(file_path, tokenizer_func=tokenizer_func)
```

If you still want to lemmatize, call some lemmatization function in tokenizer_func, as described in error message.

And now wait around 8h to process :D